# SonarCloud error on Travis: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password

Tags: travis-ci, sonarcloud

I have search a lot about this problem also here on stackoverflow, but I didn't find the solution.

Until yesterday Travis could execute sonar:sonar without any problem, but today it doesn't work and it gives me this error:

```
--- sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) @ progetto ---

    [INFO] User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
    [INFO] SonarQube version: 8.0.0
    [INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
    [INFO] Load global settings
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  04:38 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-08T15:56:40Z
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project progetto: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
```

so I change my SONAR_TOKEN creating a new one. But nothing changed.
This is my Travis file:

```
language: java

jdk: openjdk8

env: DISPLAY=:99.0

services:
   - docker
   - xvfb
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "laviniadd"
    token:
         secure: $SONAR_TOKEN
install: true
cache:
   directories:
   - $HOME/.m2
   - $HOME/.sonar/cache

script:
 - git fetch --unshallow
 - mvn -f progetto/pom.xml clean verify -Pdocker -Pjacoco coveralls:report sonar:sonar
```

I really don't know where the problem is.
I also try to generate a new token and try to use it directly without using `$SONAR_TOKEN`, but nothing changed.

Thank you in advanced.

**EDIT** This is the full error after adding -X to my travis command :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project progetto: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerPluginInstaller: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.PluginFiles: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalConfiguration: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalServerSettings: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you now **must** encrypt sonar token using

```
travis encrypt
```

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/

It used to work without encrypting token when the token was stored as secure variable in Travis.

Alternatively, if you're using a variable to store the token un-encrypted, you can change your `.travis.yml` file.

```
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: utplsql
    token:
      # Put sonar connection token generated and encrypted.
      secure: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

To:

```
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: utplsql
    token: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

This solution worked for me.